# Word order for subclause with double infinitive "lassen" in past tense

Tags: word-order, verbal-complex

> Ich bin froh, dass du mich das Auto waschen lassen hast. Es hat mir viel Spaß gemacht!

Is the ordering of "waschen lassen hast" correct, or does it need to be "hast waschen lassen"? I wanted to look up a reference, but wasn't sure which terminology to use.

Also, would the use of Präteritum "waschen ließest" sound old-fashioned or overblown?

Comment: Sometimes it is worth trying the too obvious: I simply googled for "lassen hast reihenfolge".

Comment: @Matthias Danke für den Tipp!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dazu gibt es eine Aussage bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882):

> Wenn eine Verbgruppe einen [Ersatzinfinitiv](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Ersatzinfinitiv-35882) von heißen, lassen, helfen, sehen fühlen, hören enthält und dieser Ersatzinfinitiv vom Hilfsverb haben abhängig ist, wird das finite Hilfsverb im Nebensatz in der Regel vor die Verbgruppe gestellt. Zumindest bei lassen, sehen, fühlen, hören gilt aber die Endstellung des finiten Hilfsverbs auch als korrekt.

Demzufolge sind beide Varianten möglich, die Variante mit vorgezogenem "hast" gilt als üblicher.

Das Präteritum "waschen ließest" klänge an dieser Stelle sehr übertrieben. Ich würde sogar überlegen, ob ich mich nicht verhört habe und der Konjunktiv gemeint gewesen sein könnte, so wie in

> Ich würde mich freuen, wenn Du mich das Auto waschen ließest.

Comment: Ich denke, *ließt* ist die üblichere Vergangenheitsform. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:lassen#Finite_Formen

Comment: @CarstenS Selbst bei Wiktionary nur als zweite Option für den Indikativ, aber nicht für den Konjunktiv. Beim Duden sogar nur _ließest_: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lassen#grammatik.

Comment: Ich wollte Dir recht geben, dass *ließest* sich nach Konjunktiv anhört, und ich würde es wahrscheinlich nur dafür benutzen und für die Vergangenheit *ließt*. Andererseits würde ich diese Form wahrscheinlich auch nicht benutzen. Und natürlich kann es sein, dass meine Sprache verschludert ist.